# Character + is converted to %2B in HTTP Post

Tags: http, post, escaping

I'm adding functionality to a GM script we use here at work, but when trying to post (cross site may I add) to another page, my posting value of CMD is different than what it is on the page.

It's supposed to be Access+My+Account+Info but the value that is posted becomes Access%2BMy%2BAccount%2BInfo.

So I guess my question is: What's escaping my value and how do I make it not escape? And if there's no way to unescape it, does anyone have any ideas of a workaround?

Thanks!

[image: My Issue]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`%2B` is the code for a `+`. You (or whatever framework you're using) should already be decoding the POST data server-side...

Comment: I realize that %2B is +, but if I pass it to the form as %2B instead of +, it breaks.

Comment: Pass it to what form? Whatever is processing the form data server-side should be decoding the values. `+` wouldn't be valid in URL encoded POST data because it's used to represent a space, it has to be encoded.

Comment: James you made something click in my head. I replaced the + with spaces and it works. haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick remark: If you want to decode a path segment, you can use UriUtils (spring framework):

```
@Test
public void decodeUriPathSegment() {
   String pathSegment = "some_text%2B"; // encoded path segment
   String decodedText = UriUtils.decode(pathSegment, "UTF-8");
   System.out.println(decodedText);
   assertEquals("some_text+", decodedText);
}
```

Uri path segments are different from HTML escape chars (see [list](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/)). Here is an example:

```
@Test
public void decodeHTMLEscape() {
    String someString = "some_text&#43;";
    String stringJsoup = org.jsoup.parser.Parser.unescapeEntities(someString, false);
    String stringApacheCommons = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(someString);
    String stringSpring = htmlUnescape(someString);

    assertEquals("some_text+", stringJsoup);
    assertEquals("some_text+", stringApacheCommons);
    assertEquals("some_text+", stringSpring);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

/data/v50.0/query?q=SELECT Id from Case

This worked for me. Give space instead of '+'