# Combine form get variable into single variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, variables

I would like to combine multiple get variable into single variable when the user submits data in form.

For an example, if the user gives input values like "First Name : Dave, Last Name : Smith, Family Name : Dave+Villa"
then the form gives get variable as "`?fName=Dave&lName=Smith&famName=Dave+Villa`"

But i need output as "`?family=Dave-Smith-Dave+Villa`" in a single variable.

is that possible?

Also You can use javascript.

Here it is my code,

```html
<html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h4>Family Category</h4>
      <form name="userForm" action="" method="get">
      <table>
      <tr><td>First Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="fName"/></td><tr>
      <tr><td>Last Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="lName"/></td><tr>
      <tr><td>Family Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="famName"/></td><tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add Category"/></td><tr>
      </table>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Use implode in your php

Comment: do you use javascript?

Comment: yes u can use  javascript. but i dnt know how to use it..

Comment: Do you need the `-` and `+` in between or `DaveSmithDave%2BVilla` will do?

Comment: yes i need a both - and + in between string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden field input and name it `name="family"` and remove `name` from all other inputs., then we can set the value of family before we submit the form using Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Family Category</h4>
<form name="userForm" action="" method="get" onsubmit="setGetUrl()">
    <table>
        <tr><td>First Name :</td><td><input id="name" type="text" />
            <input type="text" name="family" id="family" hidden></td><tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name :</td><td><input id="lname" type="text" ></td><tr>
        <tr><td>Family Name:</td><td><input id="famName" type="text"/></td><tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add Category"/></td><tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    function getValue(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }

    function setGetUrl() {
        var name = getValue('name');
        var lname = getValue('lname');
        var famName = getValue('famName');
        document.getElementById('family').value = name + '-' + lname + '-' + famName;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hahahha! Same answer at the same time. :D

Comment: @DineshDiNu glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

We can use JavaScript to change a `hidden` variable in the form with `name=family` with the concatenated `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Family`.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    function X()
    {
        x = document.getElementById("a").value + "-" + document.getElementById("b").value + "-" + document.getElementById("c").value;
        document.getElementById("d").value = x;
    }
</script>

<h4>Family Category</h4>
<form name="userForm" action="dd.php" method="get" onsubmit="return X()">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name :</td><td><input type="text" id="a"/></td><tr>
<tr><td>Last Name :</td><td><input type="text" id="b"/></td><tr>
<tr><td>Family Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="c"/></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="hidden" id="d" name="family"/></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add Category"/></td><tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then we can submit it.

Note: Here you'll find the URL as `family=Dave-Smith-Dave%2BVilla`
Don't worry! Use

```
<?php
    echo $_GET["family"];
?>
```

and you'll see nice `Dave-Smith-Dave+Villa` there.

The reason of this %2B is [Character + is converted to %2B in HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946307/character-is-converted-to-2b-in-http-post)

Also you can find a list of URL encodings in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @DineshDiNu, julekgwa and we did the same thing at the same time, that's the height of coincidence in my SO days! :D